# Mulitline text field in sharepoint Unable to retreive text

Tags: multiline-text-field

I am creating a console application in which I have a column named "Project Description". It's a multiline text field.

After I add some text with [spaces,quotes,"(",")"] all these included in that paragraph.

1. I am unable to view the text after pasting in description field and saving it.
2. I require code to retrieve the multiline text from the list.

Comment: What is your SharePoint version? 2007? 2010? 2013?

Comment: so what do you want to do? be able to view it or want it through code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SPFieldMultiLineText multilineField = item.Fields.GetField(COLUMN_NAME) as SPFieldMultiLineText;

 if (multilineField != null)
 {
 // Get the field value as HTML
 string text = multilineField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(item[COLUMN_NAME], item);
 }
```

Comment: Good enough but how to do this with client side object model?